# 500 internal server error or blank accessing php files

Tags: php, mysql, web, apache2

I keep getting either `500 internal server error` **or** `blank page` when trying to access a `php file` in **localhost**, depending on the file.

I know this might be a recurrent problem but I can't find the solution.

I reinstalled a local website that basically access a `mysql database`. It worked in this computer before, so I assume the code is OK. I already reinstalled the database also.

`Phpinfo.php`  **is working**.

I've seen that usually is a **permission problem**, I already set **everything to 755** and the owner of the files is **"root"**.

I don't use a `.htaccess` file and I've enabled the `mod_rewrite` which I've seen also can cause this problem.

**Any hints?**

Comment: It is quite clear form the error: you're trying to access a function that doesn't exist. `session_is_registered` was removed from php 5.4.

Comment: looks like session_is_registered() is not working. But I'm not sure what that means. Have php5 changed that function?

Comment: I see, what can I do to replace it?

Comment: Look at its manual page to see how you can achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_is_registered()` was deprecated in php 5.3, and removed in php 5.4. Using `session_register()`, `session_unregister()` and `session_is_registered()` was discouraged for a long time.

Your code should simply use the `$_SESSION` superglobal, it is persisted between requests and available in scripts after calling `session_start()`.

If you want to know if you session has a given variable, simply do an isset for the array key:

```
isset($_SESSION["key"])
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a very amateur programmer as you can Imagine.

Comment: I'm assuming you're following a tutorial. You'll need to find an up-to-date one.